# WIX Adding Desktop Shortcut for current user based on a condition

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I have spent way too much time on this. Time to ask for help. I have a Visual Studio Installer package that I converted to WIX using dark.exe. In the VS installer, I have a checkbox dialog with two checkbox's to add a desktop shortcut via a .LNK file. One for add for all users, one for add for current user. This works just fine, until I convert over to WIX.

First, I get this error:

Component xxx installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.

I search google, it tells me I need a Registry value, so, I now have this:

```
<Directory Id="DesktopFolder" ShortSourceName="USER'S~1" SourceName="User's Desktop">
   <Component Id="C__7DDB9BC0582F4D92BBB635D8264B2521" Guid="{5EFFCB50-32D4-5286-E8DB-84FCEC3F8050}" Win64="yes">
     <RegistryValue 
       Root="HKCU" 
       Key="SOFTWARE\MyProduct"
       Name="InstallFolder"
       Value="%UserProfile%\Desktop"
       Type="string"
       KeyPath="yes" />
   <Condition>(CHECKBOXA2=1) AND (CHECKBOXA1&lt;&gt;1)</Condition>
     <File Id="_7DDB9BC0582F4D92BBB635D8264B2521" Name="MyLink.lnk" ShortName="MyLink.LNK" KeyPath="no" DiskId="1" Source="C:\PathToMyLink.lnk" />
 </Component>
</Directory>
```

WIX builds just fine, the installer runs just fine, however, I NEVER get the desktop shortcut for the User profile. The all users shortcut works just fine when I check that box. However, nothing I have tried will get the Users profile shortcut file in %UserProfile%\Desktop folder. I get no errors even using debug logging on the MSI.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

I failed to mention that I also have a wix bootstrap to handle installing additional items as more then one MSI at a time. I was using the MSI source from this WIX conversion in the bootstrap. I decided to specify the original VS Installer MSI for the bootstrap that that works. I can get the User's desktop icon doing this. However, I updated this conversion to install a certificate using the IIS extension which I am unable to get working in the bootstrap. So, it seems the conversion using dark is leaving something out.

Here is some relevant text from verbose logging. CHECKBOXA2 is the box to check for the Users profile. Not sure why it is being deleted? CHECKBOX 3 and 4 are hidden and not used.

MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Doing action: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX1
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 9:30:31: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX1.
Action ended 9:30:31: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX1. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Doing action: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX2
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 9:30:31: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX2.
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting CHECKBOXA2 property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 9:30:31: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX2. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Doing action: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX3
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 9:30:31: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX3.
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting CHECKBOXA3 property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 9:30:31: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX3. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Doing action: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX4
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 9:30:31: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX4.
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting CHECKBOXA4 property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 9:30:31: CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX4. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Doing action: DIRCA_TARGETDIR
MSI (c) (54:34) [09:30:31:417]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText

Another issue is that the registry entry I specified above never gets created. Could that be the whole issue here?

UPDATE: Some progress has been made. If I change the WIX XML to have the User Desktop Checkbox checked by default, then it does install the shortcut in the users desktop, and it does create the registry entry. However, it wont uninstall from Programs and features. I get error code 26351. I can remove it using the uninstall string from the registry though. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: If I run the bare MSI from WIX, all works as expected. I then build the bootstrap using the MSI, and it only works if I set "ForcePerMachine=no". This is also what causes the uninstall to fail. If I put this back to yes, the uninstall works fine, but the desktop icon created is in all users. Still beating my head on this one, hoping someone can point me to the error of my ways. Thanks.

Comment: When you're running the installer be sure to log it. Then check the log for all instances of your properties to be sure they're being set to the value you're expecting. If that all looks good then search for all instances of the component GUID to verify it is being set to the values you're expecting

Comment: I can see CHECKBOXA2 being deleted which means your condition will always be false. Not sure what you're doing with a custom action but generally if you pass a null value into a property it will effectively delete that property

Comment: I saw that as well. I then updated the default value to 1 for BOTH checkboxes and it now works. I dont like have the user see both boxes checked and having to uncheck one, but right now, that is the only way it works.